Empty Eclipse WindowBuilder
I just grabbed Eclipse WindowBuilder, but my workspace is totally empty. I'm on macOS Sonoma, with Eclipse IDE version 2024-03 (4.31.0). Here's a snapshot of what's happening. Any ideas on how to sort this out?

I've given redownloading a shot a few times, updated everything, double checeked Project Configurations, you name it. Now I'm thinking maybe it's a compatibility issue...
WindowBuilder Code:
package com.example.grade;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public MainFrame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        setContentPane(contentPane);
    }

}


According to the version number in the bottom right corner of your screenshot, you use a WindowBuilder Nightly Build which might be unstable. Please use the  latest WindowBuilder release, make sure that there are no errors in your project (see the Problems view) and show the Java code you opened in the WindowBuilder editor (add the code as text into your question formatted as Sample Code (indented by four spaces)).

I tried installing the latest WindowBuilder release and it still didn't work....I also added the code of the WindowBuilder editor

Your question still shows a cropped screenshot of a nightly build instead of the latest release and it's still unclear whether there are build or compile errors in your project that are the root problem.
